# WebBluetooth API: How to get current device's id

Tags: javascript, web, bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I'm using WebBluetooth API in Chrome 80 with experimental flag enabled.
I can retrieved all nearby devices' info with `navigator.bluetooth.requestLEScan`.
However, when it comes to the current device that I'm making scan from, there doesn't seem to be a way to retrieve information about it.
Is there anyway that I can retrieve information of the current bluetooth device?

I couldn't find anything from [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web), [here](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/), nor [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Bluetooth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web Bluetooth does not have a way to get information about the central device. Please use the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/482) that you filed to discuss use cases for this feature.